# ng new not working anymore on one windows 10 machine

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

`ng new my-app` results in "Schematic input does not validate against the Schema:

```
{
    "version":"6.2.4",
    "skipGit":false,
    "experimentalIvy":false,
    "skipInstall":false,
    "linkCli":false,
    "commit":true,
    "newProjectRoot":"projects",
    "inlineStyle":false,
    "inlineTemplate":false,
    "routing":false,
    "prefix":"app",
    "style":"css",
    "skipTests":false,
    "createApplication":true
}

Errors:

Data path "" should have required property 'name'."
```

All worked nice a week ago, the problem is not reproducable on a windows 7 machine.
The problem remains even after a fresh install of nodejs and @angular/cli@latest.
Same error message (including version 6.2.4 !?) with @angular/cli@6.0.0.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello Frits, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider formatting the error by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1026. Hope this helps. Try with downgrading cli version with npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.3

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to http://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1026 in that sense that the as missing reported property name means that ng was not able internally to generate this property from the command-line. The referred article suggests the --name flag fixes this and it does. My problem was solved by altering the command to ***ng new app-name --name app-name***.